# Running tests in Appveyor with C++ without a testing framework

Tags: c++, powershell, cmd, appveyor

We currently have set our tests up on Travis Ci by using CMakes integrated CTest, which just checks if the `int main()` returns something else than 0.

We would now like to add testing functionality to our automated windows builds in Appveyor while still keeping this simple return value check.

Every ressource for Appveyors testing we've found so far assumes we're using some kind of testing framework like MSTest, which we don't intend to do.

I found out that you can run custom CMD and Powershell testing scripts on Appveyor, which sounds like an ideal way to check the return value of our test.
Unfortunatly, we are all pretty inexperienced using CMD and Powershell  and have no clue how to achieve this.

For reference, this is the project in question: [JNF_NEAT](https://github.com/SirRade/JNF_NEAT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we set up our [.appveyor.yml](https://github.com/SirRade/Hippocrates/blob/development/.appveyor.yml) like this:

```
test_script:
  - C:\projects\jnf-neat\x64\Release\XORSolver.exe
  - C:\projects\jnf-neat\x64\Release\EvenNumbers.exe
```

where `XORSolver.exe` and `EvenNumbers.exe` are our integration tests that we already used to run on CMake.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cmake and Make for Windows too. Cmake is installed by default on build worker VM, make should be added before build. Here is appveyor.yml I created when trying to make it work:

```
install:
# Install make for Windows unsing chocolatey
  - ps: choco install make

build_script:
# Use the same commands which is used in .travis.yml
  - cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-6 CMakeLists.txt

# make fails here now
  - make 
  - make test

# Start RDP access to connect and debug
on_finish:
  - ps: $blockRdp = $true; iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/appveyor/ci/master/scripts/enable-rdp.ps1'))
```

Cmake seemed to work, while make failed. I am not very familiar with those tools, but I believe you can start from here to tune it. I also added statement to create RDP session for you to be able to connect and debug from build worker.

Thank you,

Ilya.